# how to generate UML diagrams using doxygen command in Linux

Tags: linux, uml, doxygen

I have a project in python flask.I want to generate UML diagram for the project.What are the commands for generating from Linux command line?

Comment: Please provide more information / show what you have tried, the question here does not show anything. doxygen has the possibility generate UML diagrams. Please dive into it, see e.g. the options UML_LOOK in the doxygen documentation and doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile).

Answer (score 1):

Is the usage of plant UML and doxygen an answer for you ?

See 
[You can use Doxygen and PlantUML together to integrate UML diagrams into generated documentation :](http://plantuml.com/doxygen)

or
[Doxygen forum](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Working-on-adding-PlantUML-class-diagrams-td7122.html)